# Plugin not appearing after uploading it via FTP

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am trying to manually add a new plugin to WordPress site (I need to add a customized plugin).

I do it by:

1. uploading it via Ftp server (with FTPS connection) to `/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins`
2. Copy/paste to `/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins`

But, I am not able to see it on WordPress site under plugin section.

I am using:

1. WordPress 4.7
2. Filezilla (FTP client) and VSFTPD (Ubuntu FTP server).
3. Ubuntu 16.10

Any ideas as to what the issue is?

Comment: What happens when you try this? Is the file just not appearing on the ftp or is the plugin not activiating correctly?

Comment: Have you unzipped the plugin file? Would you please edit your question and paste the plugin's header comment into your question?

Comment: Try zip your plugin folder and upload from backend OR try re upload your plugin once again.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the file owner and the file permissions, if your hosting is not set up properly the files uploaded might be owned by a different user without permission for the web server user to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Plugin work on localhost? Was it corrected created? The main PHP file of the plugin must have the same name of the folder and the main PHP file must have the following before everything:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WordPress.org Plugin
Plugin URI:  https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/
Description: Basic WordPress Plugin Header Comment
Version:     20160911
Author:      WordPress.org
Author URI:  https://developer.wordpress.org/
License:     GPL2
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: wporg
Domain Path: /languages
*/
```

It is also important that you do not close the PHP tag at the end.
I hope it helps.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/header-requirements/

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue and whilst i cant provide i direct answer i found a workaround. Just take you plugin files (usually the .php and .css) highlight, right click, compress to archive (you need winzip/winrar) then go to the plugins section of the back end of your site and upload the zip file - whn i do that wordpress finds it. No idea why